# How is the modulo number selected to build the hash table in DHP algorithm?

Tags: data-mining

I'm trying to understand the DHP(Direct Hashing and Pruning) algorithm and I got stuck at explaining the selection of modulo number.
The [paper](http://user.it.uu.se/~kostis/Teaching/DM-01/Handouts/PCY.pdf) shows an example of using the hash function at page 7: `h{{x y}) = ((order of x)*10 + (order of y)) mod 7`

My questions are:

1. What are the basis to define the function this way?
2. How is the modulo number selected(7, in this example)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. One possible reason to define the function this way is that it works for their example. It is an academic paper so it incentivized to find a novel solution that works on a specific dataset. In the paper, it is a synthetic dataset.
2. When building hash tables it is best practice to pick a prime (7 in this case) to minimize the number of collisions when using the modulo operator. The fact that is small prime is a clue that they building a toy system.